# Получение версии Windows

Tags: winapi, c++

В библиотеке требуется знать, под какой версией Windows (Win7, Vista etc) запущено приложение. Подскажите, как получить данную информацию от системы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У windows API есть такая функция GetVersionEx, которая вытаскивает исчерпывающую информацию о версии операционной системы...

Answer (score 2):

PEB.NtMajorVersion, NtMinorVersion, NtBuildNumber или в US. Лучше из US, так как данный блок version-independent:

> WARNING: This structure must have exactly the same layout for 32- and
> 64-bit systems. The layout of this structure cannot change and new
> fields can only be added at the end of the structure (unless a gap
> can be exploited). Deprecated fields cannot be deleted. Platform
> specific fields are included on all systems.
>
> Layout exactness is required for Wow64 support of 32-bit applications
> on Win64 systems.
>
> The layout itself cannot change since this structure has been exported
> in ntddk, ntifs.h, and nthal.h for some time.

Непосредственно структура:

```
NT_PRODUCT_TYPE NtProductType;
BOOLEAN ProductTypeIsValid;

//
// The NT Version.
//
// N. B. Note that each process sees a version from its PEB, but if the
//       process is running with an altered view of the system version,
//       the following two fields are used to correctly identify the
//       version
//

ULONG NtMajorVersion;
ULONG NtMinorVersion;
```

Смещение поля NtMajorVersion: 0x7FFE026C

Answer (score 1):

Информацию о версии ОС можно также найти и в реестре.
Искать в

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions`